# Getting KMZ file with image to show in Google My Maps

Tags: google-mymaps

Maybe this isn't possible but does anyone know a way I could get a KMZ file that includes a raster image to save into Google My Maps.  I can get the KMZ to display fine with image by uploading it to Google Docs and searching for it in Google Maps but when I go to save it in My Maps, the KMZ layer disappears and thus doesn't save it.  I would use the KML import in My Maps but it doesn't seem to support uploading the imagery, only the vector data.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the public url of your KML/KMZ file?

Comment: I did make it public but I would rather not share the link on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Google MyMaps KMZ is limited compared to Google Earth by Google Maps servers
(file sizes are also limited to 10mb)

Is your KML/KMZ publicly accessible?
you should be able to overlay your data in google maps

Test it out like this example:
http://maps.google.com/?q=http://www.vta.org/bike_information/scc_bikeways.kmz

Is your KML/KMZ vaild - test it out here:

http://www.kmlvalidator.com/home.htm

Comment: Even in your sample, it won't save to My Maps.  There is a link in the top right that says "Save to My Maps".  I click on that and it takes you to My Maps and displays the KMZ but it doesn't save it or have an option to save unless I'm missing something?   If you click Create new map, the KMZ disappears.

Comment: That because that functionality has been deprecated (uses map data api)   http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/11/maps-data-api-deprecation-announcement.html you need to upload to fusion tables now.

Comment: You really sure the the deprecation of the map data api has anything to do with Google Map "My Maps" feature?  If so, why would they leave that link in there if it doesn't do anything?  Seems strange, that they wouldn't remove that link if it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Mapperz neither of your links work anymore